# How retrieve "locality" from json google places api

Tags: java, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How retrieve "locality" from json google places api

in this json response:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "1623",
            "short_name" : "1623",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
     {
        "long_name" : "1/2 N Cahuenga Boulevard",
        "short_name" : "1/2 N Cahuenga Boulevard",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "CA",
            "short_name" : "CA",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "US",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
     {
        "long_name" : "90028",
        "short_name" : "90028",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
```

i am using this code to get "lat" and "lng" :

```
            JSONObject jsonLocation = c.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");

            places_latitude = jsonLocation.getString("lat");
            places_longitude = jsonLocation.getString("lng");
```

how do i get the "locality" value ?  i'am using java.

Thank you,

Carlos.

Comment: The problem is, that there is no locality value.

What you need to do instead is to iterate over the parts that google serves you as address_components, look into their type and stop when you find the right one. Then get the long_name for that object.

Comment: You should really use the ENUM AddressComponentType. Here's an example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57612219/9278333

Answer (score 1):

I follow your way.

```
JSONArray address_components = c.getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("address_components");

JSONObject obj = address_components.getJSONObject(2)
/*
 obj is 
  {
            "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
   }
 */
String your_result = obj.getJSONArray("types").get(0).toString();
```

The original json should be

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "1623",
            "short_name" : "1623",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
     {
        "long_name" : "1/2 N Cahuenga Boulevard",
        "short_name" : "1/2 N Cahuenga Boulevard",
        "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "short_name" : "Los Angeles",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "CA",
            "short_name" : "CA",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "US",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
     {
        "long_name" : "90028",
        "short_name" : "90028",
        "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
     }
    ]
   }
}
```